# Reach a target slope value by eliminating outlier using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

I have a dataset from which I can eliminate maximum of two data points to reach a target slope of 10. My criteria for outlier rejection is say if the slope is within +/-5% if the target value (10), it is ALL OK. However, anything above this shall be deleted.

A trial data set is as follows:

[image: Dataset]

As can be seen from the left side of the image, three slopes=11.6,10.5 and 9.4 are obtained. However the target slope is 10.

On the right side of the data, I removed the data points which were skewing up the slope i.e., not allowing it to reach to a target slope of 10.

This is only a constructed dataset but the concept is similar to what I need with the final dataset.

How do I go about doing it in python? Any help in this matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Can you please attach your trial data as a .csv file? Also, please post any Python code you have tried so far.

Comment: @feedMe, how do I attach csv file here?

Comment: @feedMe, I am a newbie and Python and can do small snippets of codes. However, this looks a high level problem for me. I need to know which path to follow and then I can start looking into different codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, this can be done in python if you already know the slope you want but you need to be careful with it if you have a lot of datas.
Second with a criteria of 5 per cent, the slope 10.5 won't be corrected.

**the solution you asked for**

```
#some imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = read_csv('your_file.csv')
state = 'USA'
desire_slope = 10
x = df[df['Country']==state][x]
y = df[df['Country']==state][y]

'''to use for test
x = [ 4+(i/10) for i in range(100)]
y = [c*11+norm.rvs()*4 for c in x ]
'''
z = [abs(v-desire_slope*c) for v,c in zip(y,x)]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print(slope)
if(abs(slope-desire_slope)/slope<0.05):
    print("slope is fine")
else:
    sorted_index_pos = [index for index, num in sorted(enumerate(z), key=lambda x: x[-1])][-2:]
    print(sorted_index_pos)
    del x[sorted_index_pos[-1]]
    del y[sorted_index_pos[-1]]
    del x[sorted_index_pos[0]]
    del y[sorted_index_pos[0]]

new_slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print(new_slope)
```

*Output*:

```
11.08066739990693
[78, 85]
11.026005655263733
```

**Why you need to be carefull**

first we don't take in consideration the intercept and this could be a problem. Plus, if i run the following:

```
x = [ 4+(i/100) for i in range(1000)]
y = [c*10+norm.rvs()*4 for c in x ]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print("the slope here is: "+str(slope))
z = [c*slope for c in x]
print("average of values: "+str(sum(x)/len(x)))
plt.plot(x,y,'b',x,z,'r-')
```

i get the following output:

```
the slope here is: 10.04367376783041
average of values: 8.995
```

[image]

Wich shows that the points are not necesseraly on distributed equally on both sides of the slope. Getting ride of the point far away may imbalance even more the dataset and thus won't improve the slope. So be carreful when doing so

Comment: thanks for the code. I will soon look into this. I have excel file for the data. Which part of the code pulls data from some xlsx or csv file? Will you be OK to help out with that :)

Comment: i ll add the lines (would be easier with a csv tho)

Comment: I am unable to add csv files to stackoverflow. Thus did not add it.

Comment: but you have indeed a csv file? have you done any groupe by? Do you wish me to use the example you have provided?

Comment: I do have a csv file. I am unable to upload it. Yes Please use the example I provided. That is the way I use my data set. It is similar kind of. Added u on Linkedin.

Comment: i gave you the example for USA.

Comment: thanks. Where do I put the groupby in this code? I don't need output only for USA. However for other sets too.

Comment: you want to update your dataframe? or create a new one just for the datas you keep?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180724/discussion-between-excelislife-and-alexis).

Comment: in your code, which 'x' is a column name and which 'x' is not the column name?

Comment: @excelislife i've uploaded the code for you xlsx on a gist, check the discussion